# UIControl subclass delayed response

Tags: ios, ipad, uitouch, uicontrol

I have a custom subclass of UIControl called CheckboxView, which simply draws a checkmark inside a rect when a user taps the rect. This is added as a cell in a tableView, which is located in the main container, AttributeFormView.

As expected, when a user taps the rect, -endTrackingWithTouch is fired and the checkmark is drawn properly.

However, if I add a subview to AttributeFormView that contains a tableView with the checkboxView cell, there is a significant delayed response to the the UITouch in the checkBoxView. All of the other cells in the tableView respond appropriately, but in order to get the checkmark to appear, the user has to tap & hold the rect for ~3sec.

I put:

```
CGPoint testpoint = [touch locationInView:self];
```

inside -endTrackingWithTouch to make sure the right view was being touched, which it is, but this 3sec latency is a problem.

Any ideas as to why there would be such a significant latency?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. In my case it was because of a gesture recognizer I had on the main view controllers view. Once I moved the gesture recognizer into its own view, the problem was sorted!

Hope that helps

Comment: I had this issue also and this fixed it! Thanks Benson.